# How do I make author image circular in WordPress using CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress

I want to make the author's image circular.  [Here's the link to my site.](https://www.einsstark.tech/reverse-image-search-engines-20/)[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gube6.png)

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css:

```
.avatar-35 {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I was using .author-avatar. My mistake. :)